# Pegar até a 3 posição do foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um `foreach` que imprime todas as categorias de um `JSON`. Como que eu faço para ele pegar somente até a 3 posição e parar o `loop`? A questão é que quero criar no menu uma `ul` com 3 categorias e dentro dela crie uma outra `li` com um sub-menu listando o resto delas. Se estiver 10 categorias então ele lista as 3 primeiras nas 3 primeiras `li` e depois as 7 neste submenu dentro da `li` seguinte.

Segue o código:

```
var quantidadeElementos = retorno.data.length;

            var i = 0;
            while (i <= quantidadeElementos)
            {

              if (i == 3)
              {
                  retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
                 {
                   console.log(item.nome);

                 })

                break;
              }

              i++;
            }
```

Comment: loop dentro loop?

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer logo um slice assim? `var quantidadeElementos = retorno.data.length.slice(0, 3);`?

Comment: ou assim `$.each(retorno.data, function(i, j){ if( i < 3 )  console.log(j.nome); else break; })`

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente. O meu erro foi não passar os parâmetros necessários para a função funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema esta dentro do segundo `loop`, pode fazer desta forma:

```
var quantidadeElementos = retorno.data.length;

var i = 0;
while (i <= quantidadeElementos) {
    if (i < 3) {
        console.log(retorno.data[i].nome);
        break;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Outro problema que tinha é que se a sua comparação continuasse sendo `i == 3`, ele iria rodar o `loop` 4 vezes, isso porque a variável `i` inicia com o valor `0`. Essa comparação foi substituída por `i < 3`.